# Need to combine the sales of 2 records with different ID's and the record with highest sale id should be in the result set

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with records belonging to same person but the person was assigned with 2 different id's.
I need to combine the sales and then hold on to the id having highest sales.

For Example:

```
ID  Name    Sales

1   ABC     10

4   ABC     60

5   xyz     100

6   xyz     10
```

I need result as

```
ID  Name    Sales

4   ABC     70

5   XYZ     110
```

Please help me with a sql query for the above.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
create table #mytable
(id int,
name nvarchar(20),
Sales int)

insert into #mytable
values
        (1,'ABC',10),
        (4,'ABC',60),
        (5,'xyz',100),
        (6,'xyz',10)


select (select top(1) ID    
        from #mytable r2
        where r2.name=r1.name
                and r2.Sales=MAX(r1.Sales))as ID,
        name,
        sum(Sales)      
from #mytable r1
group by name


drop table #mytable
```